# Windows DNS multi level search

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

We have a domain like `company.example`, and various subdomains under it, like `prod.company.example`, `qa.company.example`.

Every desktop is in the `company.example` DNS search domain.

I'd like to resolve names like "`server.prod`" or "`db.qa`". So the DNS resolver should attach the search domain not only to single hostname, but multi-level names, too. It works perfectly on Linux or Mac boxes, but not on Windows.

I know there's a registry to enable this, but I could find it anywhere and that drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing on Windows by configuring the Ethernet adapter and going to advanced Ethernet settings >> DNS >> and selecting 'Append these DNS suffixes(in order).

You can also set them using Powershell Windows management instrumentation cmdlets from an elevated shell.

```
# Add multiple DNS Suffixes (append)
$DNSsuffixes =  “Contoso.com”,”Child.Contoso.com”
Invoke-Wmimethod -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Name setDNSSuffixSearchOrder -ArgumentList @($DNSSuffixes),$null 

# Add just a single DNS suffix (overwrite)
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Name setDNSSuffixSearchOrder -Argument "contoso.com"
```

Comment: Yeah, but then I have to add a dozen or more subdomains one by one.
And even worse if I have the same hostname in different domains I will always get the first only.

Comment: if its a windows DNS server then the subdomains will need a delegation record, i.e. delegated from the parent domain https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771640(v=ws.11)

Comment: It is correctly delegated. As I said it works perfectly from any non-windows machine.